# Utilize symmetry in tensor contractions

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose there is a tensor contraction

```
T3[A,B,C,D] = T1[A,B,a,b] * T2[a,b,C,D]
```

where

```
T1[A,B,a,b]  = T1[B,A,b,a], T2[a,b,C,D] = T2[b,a,D,C]
```

Hence, `T3[A,B,C,D] = T3[B,A,D,C]`

I tried to use two types of python code

```
import numpy as np
import time


N = 20

T1 = np.random.rand(N, N, N, N)
T2 = np.random.rand(N, N, N, N) 
T3 = np.zeros((N,N,N,N))  

# symmetrize T1/T2
for a in range(N):
  for b in range(a+1,N):
    for c in range(N):
      for d in range(N):
        T1[b,a,d,c] = T1[a,b,c,d]
        T2[b,a,d,c] = T2[a,b,c,d]                
#1st approach
start = time.time()
out = np.einsum('ABab,abCD->ABCD', T1, T2, optimize=True)
end = time.time()

print('time2',end - start)
print(out[0,0,0,0])
#2nd approach
start = time.time()
for D in range(N):
  for C in range(d):
    for B in range(N):
      for A in range(N):
        T3[A,B,C,D] = np.einsum('ab,ab->', T1[A,B,:,:], T2[:,:,C,D], optimize=True)
        
  for C in range(d+1,N):
    for B in range(N):
      for A in range(N):      
        T3[A,B,C,D] = T3[B,A,D,C]
  

end = time.time()

print('time3',end - start)
print(T3[0,0,0,0])
```

The second approach is much slower than the first one. 0.01 vs 15 sec. Is there any way to make the 2nd approach faster?

Comment: Using compiled `numpy` functions/methods is usually faster than multiple python level iterations. Counting operations as you might do in a uniformly compiled code is not useful.

Comment: Perhaps. I try to use nested loops to utilize the symmetry, but gets slower